# Why does std::move prevent RVO (return value optimization)?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, return-value-optimization

In many cases when returning a local from a function, RVO (return value optimization) kicks in. However, I thought that explicitly using `std::move` would at least enforce moving when RVO does not happen, but that RVO is still applied when possible. However, it seems that this is not the case.

```
#include "iostream"

class HeavyWeight
{
public:
    HeavyWeight()
    {
        std::cout << "ctor" << std::endl;
    }

    HeavyWeight(const HeavyWeight& other)
    {
        std::cout << "copy" << std::endl;
    }

    HeavyWeight(HeavyWeight&& other)
    {
        std::cout << "move" << std::endl;
    }
};

HeavyWeight MakeHeavy()
{
    HeavyWeight heavy;
    return heavy;
}

int main()
{
    auto heavy = MakeHeavy();
    return 0;
}
```

I tested this code with VC++11 and GCC 4.71, debug and release (`-O2`) config. The copy ctor is never called. The move ctor is only called by VC++11 in debug config. Actually, everything seems to be fine with these compilers in particular, but to my knowledge, RVO is optional.

However, if I explicitly use `move`:

```
HeavyWeight MakeHeavy()
{
    HeavyWeight heavy;
    return std::move(heavy);
}
```

the move ctor is always called. So trying to make it "safe" makes it worse.

My questions are:

- Why does `std::move` prevent RVO?
- When is it better to "hope for the best" and rely on RVO, and when should I explicitly use `std::move`? Or, in other words, how can I let the compiler optimization do its work and still enforce move if RVO is not applied?

Comment: Why do people still talk about "hope for the best" these days? What kind of compiler are they using that has C++11 support but can't RVO properly?

Comment: Copy elision (the mechanism behind RVO) is permitted only under certain, strict conditions. Writing `std::move` prevents those conditions from being met.

Comment: @KerrekSB And these conditions prevented by std::move are...?

Comment: std::move prevents `NRVO` (_named_ `RVO`). `RVO` in general is not affected (afaik)

Comment: @KerrekSB Can you point to a reference outlining the reasoning behind preventing this? Does move elision ever happen?

Comment: @stefan: Nope,  
    return std::move(HeavyWeight());  
still calls the move ctor.

Comment: @Troy: Move elision does happen, but not when explicitly using std::move. Funny stuff.

Comment: I've been thinking I was just being thorough by doing explicit std::move's, instead it seems I've been sabotaging myself! ;)

Comment: @cdoubleplusgood I didn't say that compiler will do `RVO` in the `std::move` case. I only said, that they can't do `NRVO`, but (as I said, afaik) still can do `RVO`. It's implementation dependent.

Comment: @Troy: You're not alone.

Comment: The move can still be elided if the compiler can prove it doesn't change the program's behaviour.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: The problem case is the one where behaviour change *is* permitted, namely omitting copy/move constructor calls. Since the test case by definition must contain side effects, you're limited to optimizations that rely on copy elision and play by the rules.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The cases where copy and move elision is allowed is found in section 12.8 §31 of the Standard (version N3690):

> When certain criteria are met, an implementation is allowed to omit the copy/move construction of a class object, even if the constructor selected for the copy/move operation and/or the destructor for the object have side effects. In such cases, the implementation treats the source and target of the omitted copy/move operation as simply two different ways of referring to the same object, and the destruction of that object occurs at the later of the times when the two objects would have been destroyed without the optimization. This elision of copy/move operations, called *copy elision*, is permitted in the following circumstances (which may be combined to eliminate multiple copies):

> - in a `return` statement in a function with a class return type, when the expression is the name of a non-volatile automatic object (other than a function or catch-clause parameter) with the same cv-unqualified type as the function return type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by constructing the automatic object directly into the function’s return value

- [...]
- when a temporary class object that has not been bound to a reference (12.2) would be copied/moved to a class object with the same cv-unqualified type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by constructing the temporary object directly into the target of the omitted copy/move
- [...]

(The two cases I left out refer to the case of throwing and catching exception objects which I consider less important for optimization.)

Hence in a return statement copy elision can only occur, if the expression is **the name of a local variable.** If you write `std::move(var)`, then it is not the name of a variable anymore. Therefore the compiler cannot elide the move, if it should conform to the standard.

Stephan T. Lavavej talked about this at [Going Native 2013](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Don-t-Help-the-Compiler) [(Alternative source)](https://youtu.be/AKtHxKJRwp4?t=2284) and explained exactly your situation and why to avoid `std::move()` here. Start watching at minute 38:04. Basically, when returning a local variable of the return type then it is usually treated as an rvalue hence enabling move by default.

Comment: This is the answer I was hoping for. I'm not happy with the situation, but I understand better.

Comment: We should probably fix is so that `return std::move` can be elided.  If we could tell C++ that the reference return value of a function is guaranteed to be the same as one particular reference input value of the function, a few interesting results could open up.  (Elision from non-trivial expressions, lifetime extension of a temporary input argument to a function without returning a temporary, for two: the second of which is IMHO more important).

Comment: Yes, I don't understand the rational for not being able to elide this.  It is just more difficult to do, allowing compiler writers more time?

Comment: @Adrian I mean allowing it is not going to "give them less time". Guaranteeing would. If it's just allowed, they don't have to implement it.

Comment: @TomášRůžička, do you mean _not_ allowed?

Comment: @Adrien When standard says "you cannot do this optimization" the implementators don't have to do the work yes. But if they said "You CAN but don't have to" the implamantators don't have to do extra work. ... if they don't want to ... hence not allowing the optimization is not giving them any time

It would be something else if they said "You have to do this optimalization"

Comment: TL;DR: "when returning a local variable of the return type then it is usually treated as an rvalue hence enabling move by default."

Answer (score 18):

> how can I let the compiler optimization do its work and still enforce move if RVO is not applied?

Like this:

```
HeavyWeight MakeHeavy()
{
    HeavyWeight heavy;
    return heavy;
}
```

Transforming the return into a move is mandatory.

Comment: So returning a local is guaranteed to be a move in worst case, and RVO applies in best case?

Comment: I guess I need to do some grep'ping for `return std::move` ;)

Comment: That would actually be a useful warning.

Comment: @cdoubleplusgood Almost.  Returning a local non-parameter directly is guaranteed to `move` in the worst case.  Something as innocuous as `return condition?heavy1:heavy2;` may prevent the implicit `move`, while `if (condition) return heavy1; return heavy2;` would not.  It is somewhat fragile.