# c++ std::move is bad here?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, rvo

Let's suppose that I have `struct Foo` with move `constructor` and `operator=(Foo&&)`, and I used it as data member:

```
Foo f()
{
  Foo foo;
  //code
  return foo; 
}
struct Boo {
Foo foo;
Boo() {
  foo = f();//1
  foo = std::move(f());//2
}
};
```

In case **(2)** I actually not need `std::move`,
but what if I used it here, does this make something bad,
like preventing optimization?

I read this: [Why does std::move prevent RVO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19267408/why-does-stdmove-prevent-rvo)

and find out that changing `return foo;` to `return std::move(foo);` cause disabling of `RVO`, but what about **(2)** does it cause the similar situation? And if so, why?

Comment: Copy elision wouldn't apply in this case anyway because you are calling `foo.operator=` . It'd be relevant if you had `Foo foo = std::move(f());` which is initialization.

Comment: @M.M But `clang 3.7` warn about this, so I wonder, is it bug in warning generation, or I missed something

Comment: It can be bad for reasons that aren't performance reasons too. In your case for #2, you care calling std::move(f()) on something that is already a rhr, so the move is wasted characters. My rule of thumb is that you should avoid std::move unless you have to, and you only have to when you are transferring ownership in a non-trivial way.

Comment: So far as I know the proper approach to `std::move` is using it when transferring data to a subroutine, not from. But I am also waiting for the answer ;)

Comment: @Galik You're right, but in case 2 is it a 'bad' approach to explicitly tell the compiler to move? (although it is already ready to be moved), if so why would it be bad?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's redundant and confusing. Just because I can write `std::add_pointer_t<void>` instead of `void*`, or `std::add_lvalue_reference_t<Foo>` (or `Foo bitand`) instead of `Foo&`, doesn't mean I should.

It also matters in other contexts:

```
auto&& a = f(); // OK, reference binding to a temporary extends its lifetime
auto&& b = std::move(f()); // dangling
```

and so, if `Foo` is something that can be iterated over,

```
for(const auto& p : f()) {} // OK
for(const auto& p : std::move(f())) {} // UB
```

And in your example, if the assignment operator is implemented as copy-and-swap (`operator=(Foo)`), then `foo = std::move(f())` forces a non-elidable move, while `foo = f()` can elide the move from `f()`'s return value to the argument of `operator=`.

Comment: In that first example, `b` does NOT seem dangling when compiled by `VS2013`. (Haven't tested with any other compiler yet). Could you please provide a little more information on that?

Comment: @DeanSeo Neither [clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/607b0d720af30b9e) nor [gcc](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/698d5c5271c8f1c8) will extend the lifetime of the temporary. The former will even emit some nice performance warnings.

Comment: @MatthäusBrandl I don't think `std::move(f())` is the temporary yet, but it'll likely be moved very soon as an xvalue. So it's not yet moved ... ? (meaning not dangling). I posted this a long time ago so maybe I need some time to catch up.

Comment: @DeanSeo I realized but figured you might be interested. I guess after the call to `std::move()` the result of `f()` may be destructed legally before passing the reference on to `b`. Seems like an evaluation order problem.

Comment: @MatthäusBrandl Woah, didn't think of that! I will get a little deeper about that later.