# Returning a pair of objects

Tags: c++, move-semantics, return-value-optimization, nrvo

The following is an anti-pattern:

```
auto f() {
  std::vector<int> v(100000);
  return std::move(v); // no need to use std::move thanks to RVO (return value optimization)
}
```

Using a `std::move` can even produce worst code (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19272035/1583122))

However, what should I do in the following situation:

```
auto f() {
  std::vector<int> v0(100000);
  std::vector<int> v1(100000);
  return std::make_pair(std::move(v0),std::move(v1)); // is the move needed?
}
```

Comment: In the second situation, the move is not **needed**, *per se*.  Providing the `move` only makes the code have 200,000 less copies, so it'll be more performant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second snippet,

```
auto f() {
  std::vector<int> v0(100000);
  std::vector<int> v1(100000);
  return std::make_pair(std::move(v0),std::move(v1)); // is the move needed?
}
```

`return` returns the result of the `std::make_pair()` function. That's an RValue.

However, the OP's question probably condenses to whether (or why not) [Named Return Value Optimization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) still applies to `v0`/`v1` when returned as a `std::pair`.

Thereby, it's overlooked that `v0`/`v1` aren't subject of `return` anymore, but become arguments of `std::make_pair()`. As such, `v0`/`v1` are LValues – `std::move(v0), std::move(v1)` have to be applied to turn them into RValues if move-semantic is intended.

---

[Demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/19f2d0a710bdb1dd):

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct Vector {
  Vector(size_t n)
  {
    std::cout << "Vector::Vector(" << n << ")\n";
  }
  Vector(const Vector&)
  {
    std::cout << "Vector::Vector(const Vector&)\n";
  }
  Vector(const Vector&&)
  {
    std::cout << "Vector::Vector(const Vector&&)\n";
  }
  
};

auto f1() {
  Vector<int> v(100000);
  return std::move(v); // over-pessimistic
}

auto f2() {
  Vector<int> v(100000);
  return v; // allows NRVO
}

auto f3() {
  Vector<int> v0(100000);
  Vector<int> v1(100000);
  return std::make_pair(v0, v1); // copy constructor called for v0, v1
}    

auto f4() {
  Vector<int> v0(100000);
  Vector<int> v1(100000);
  return std::make_pair(std::move(v0),std::move(v1)); // move constructor called for v0, v1
}

#define DEBUG(...) std::cout << #__VA_ARGS__ << ";\n"; __VA_ARGS__ 

int main()
{
  DEBUG(f1());
  DEBUG(f2());
  DEBUG(f3());
  DEBUG(f4());
}
```

Output:

```
f1();
Vector::Vector(100000)
Vector::Vector(const Vector&&)
f2();
Vector::Vector(100000)
f3();
Vector::Vector(100000)
Vector::Vector(100000)
Vector::Vector(const Vector&)
Vector::Vector(const Vector&)
f4();
Vector::Vector(100000)
Vector::Vector(100000)
Vector::Vector(const Vector&&)
Vector::Vector(const Vector&&)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I think you mean regular RVO for `f2` since the optimization is guaranteed in C++11 (where NRVO was not mandated)

Comment: @Bérenger NVRO is not mandated. Nevertheless, I noticed that g++ uses the opportunity even with `-std=c++14` (for a longer time). (With `-std=c++11`, `auto f()` is rejected.)

Comment: @Bérenger You are correct that NVRO is not mandatory. Hence, I wrote `// allows NVRO` in `f2()`. To force RVO, you had to go with [eeroikas answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71242145/7478597), of course, i.e. `return std::vector(100000);`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the move is needed to avoid copy in the latter case.

However, this would be even better:

```
return std::make_pair(
    std::vector<int>(100000),
    std::vector<int>(100000));
```